# The script does not send the changed data

Tags: javascript, websocket, discord

I encountered a problem that my script does not send the changed data to Discord.
All other functionality works well. What could be the problem?

Here's the code:

```
var send = WebSocket.prototype.send;

WebSocket.prototype.send = function (data) {
    if (WebSocket.prototype.toString.call(data) === "[object ArrayBuffer]") {
        var array = new Uint8Array(data);
        var modules = DiscordNative.nativeModules.requireModule('discord_erlpack');
        var unpackeddata = modules.unpack(array);
        console.Log("(WS LOG) received wsdata -> " + JSON.stringify(unpackeddata));
        if (unpackeddata.op == 4) {
            unpackeddata.d.self_mute = true;
            unpackeddata.d.self_deaf = true;
            unpackeddata.d.self_video = true;
            console.log("WS Packet 4")
        } else if (unpackeddata.op == 12) {
            for (var stream of unpackeddata.d.streams) {
                stream.quality = 1;
                stream.max_bitrate = 8000;
                stream.max_framerate = 10;
                console.log("WS Packet 12")
            }
        } else if (unpackeddata.op == 24) {
            unpackeddata.d.type = 123;
            unpackeddata.d.limit = 123;
            unpackeddata.d.offset = 123;
            console.log("WS Packet 24");
        }
        var packed = modules.pack(unpackeddata);
        var buffer = packed.buffer;
        array = new Uint8Array(buffer);
        data = array;
    } else {
        console.log("(WS LOG) received wsdata -> " + data);
    }
    return send.apply(this, [data]);
}
```

Comment: The script does not send. What happened that made it "not send"? Was there an error? What did the error say? Or did just nothing happen?

Comment: Are you redefining the enter Websocket prototype? `WebSocket.prototype.toString.call(data)`... what can `toString()` give you, and why are you passing it args?